# How to activate build and run on unity hub, for android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build and run a unity project for `Android`

However, my build and run button is greyed out and i'm not sure how to activate it.

How do I activate it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uncheck **Export Project** toggle in your build settings.

Answer (score 0):

The **Export Project** bool literally exports the project as a **Gradle** project so that you can import it into **Android Studio**. Unchecking the **Export Project** will do the trick

You can find more information about building for Android [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-BuildProcess.html)